# send data from android to php, may be data not reaching php end

Tags: php, android, parsing, connection

i am trying to send some data from my android code to php file.

and trying to fetch it back from php and display it in emulator
my java code

`

```
       try{

      URL url = null;
      String s="http://10.0.2.2/welcome.php";
     url = new URL(s);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new   HttpPost(s);    
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                                                                           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
              stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
              {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
              }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }  


        finally
        {
             tx.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
          // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so
          // wrap it in another try/catch block.
          if (reader != null)
          {
            try
            {
              reader.close(); 
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {  tx.setText((CharSequence) ioe);
              ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }``
```

i am doing a stupidity by opening two different connections one for post and another for get, but problem is not with that. its with my http-post.execute method.

my php code is
       `<?php
         $pLat = $_POST['pLat'];
         $pLng = $_POST['pLng'];
         print_r("$_POST['pLat']");
         print_r("$_POST['pLng']");
       ?>`

i think i've got problem in sending my data, coz if i echo sumthing on my php it shows on my emulator.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really recommend that you use a library to perform HTTP requests. Things get a lot easier. Take a look at [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for instance. An example of POSTing data and handling a response:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
rp.put("pLat", "some value");
rp.put("pLong", "some other value");
client.post("http://10.0.2.2/welcome.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public final void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle your response here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
        // something went wrong
    }               
});
```

Comment: thank you britzl , your ans really helped me.. n amy code is running fine now.

Comment: and i also added that aysnc http client jar file. thanx alot. again :)

Comment: Great. I'm glad to help. You may want to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: sir, ive got a littel itsy-bitsy prob, that onSuccess take string parameter and i need it too take in arrays so i can collect multiple values from my db and use them the way i want.

Comment: Ok, so the server will pass a bunch of values back to the client? In that case I need to know a bit about the kind of values you wish to return to the client. How many values? What data types? My suggestion is that the server returns data in JSON format, or possibly a delimited list (of key value pairs?). In either case a String is what you will get back. You need to parse that string and convert it into whatever datatypes you need. (PS you up/downvote an answer by using the up and down arrows next to my answer)

Comment: sir  i am getting the values in form of string, and i want them to be an array , i used a trick of using implode() on php script to add "," and use split() on android code, so i cud save things in and array(String []s), a string array. i'll post my code on monday,its in office actually . plz visit back on monday , and to vote up your ans i need repo of 15+, ive got ive got on 14 now :P

Comment: please upvote this ques too soo other ppl can also knw about android ascynchronous http clinet.